# Epic Badge: Earned at least 200 reputation on 50 days

Tags: support, reputation, badges

I am user of [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for 73 days and I have [723 Reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612606/vito-brothers-apoyan) on my 50s day in Stackoverflow my reputation was more then 200. Thats why I want to ask you, why I didn't get Epic Badge?

Comment: I want one! Gimme gimme.

Comment: +1 I'm not interested in this kind of issue, but after taking a look, it's true that it's very confusing and downvoting this question is unfair.

Comment: I have never *once* been confused by the wording of the reputation badges. But apparently, there's been a number of people recently who have been, and all of them come directly to Meta to whine about not having received the badges to which they're surely entitled... It's somewhat tiring.

Comment: We do have a more detailed list of badges [with user-generated descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) for this purpose. It wouldn't have helped the OP, though; his problem was a misunderstanding of the distinction between "on" and "in."

Comment: @viTo Brothers Apoyan. You might want to note that at the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/reputation you can see how many days you've hit 200

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You misunderstood what it means.  To get the badge, you need to have received 200 reputation (the reputation cap) in a single day for 50 days total.  It doesn't mean that you have at least 200 reputation after 50 days, that would be too easy.  ;)

Comment: And what does this mean ? Earned at least 200 reputation on 150 days

Comment: It mean that I must earn 200 reputation in a single day for 150 days total ?

Comment: @ViTo: Yes that's right.

Comment: But there was a badge "Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day" Thats the difference ? I cant understand. It mean if I get 200 reputation in a single day I will get all 3 badge ? Yes ? Am I right ?

Comment: @ViTo: Suppose today you earned exactly 200 rep.  By doing so, you have earned the Mortarboard badge.  You will not earn the Epic nor the Legendary badges yet.  You would need to earn 200 rep in a single day another 49 times to earn the Epic badge and another 149 times to earn the Legendary badge.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Okey now I Understand ! Thanks a lot ! But why -1 to this answer I cant understand ) Good luck !

Comment: @ViTo: To be honest, I don't know why someone downvoted the question.  You misunderstood something about the site and asked about it.  It's not a bad question and apparently reading about it again didn't help you understand it better.  Unfortunately people will vote negatively without understanding what the question really is about.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I think people are stupid ) Good luck to good people like you ! thanks !

Comment: Replacing "on 50 days" with "on 50 separate days" might avoid these misunderstandings?